# Possible to charge device with Google Pixel phone through USB-C?

Tags: charging, google-pixel

Is it possible to charge an external device using Google Pixel smartphone as a battery? In other words, can I change the charging direction (reverse charge) so I can charge e.g. a laptop using my Google Pixel as power source?

Answer (score 1):

- [Pixel phones support USB C Power Delivery](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/forum/AAAAb4-OgUsb5UEZ0RGJTY/?hl=by)
- [This standard says](https://www.usb.org/usb-charger-pd)

> Power direction is no longer fixed. This enables the product with the power (Host or Peripheral) to provide the power

Which translates to reverse charging

- Reddit users [confirm reverse charging with Pixel](https://www.reddit.com/r/GooglePixel/comments/5obpzt/psa_you_can_use_you_pixel_as_a_power_bank_to/#thing_t1_dci8bwe)

How efficient charging your laptop would be dependent on the state of charge of phone / laptop , battery capacity of laptop but theoretically **yes, you can** ( you would need USB cable with male connections at both ends)